# GAE could not set min_instances for automatic scaling

Tags: google-app-engine, google-apps, google-app-engine-python

I'm trying to configure my GAE project to use **min_instances=0** when running over **automatic scaling** option.

I followed all steps on [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/setting-autoscaling-params-in-explorer) but after to click "EXECUTE", I received a BAD Request error:

[image]

The error informs "This field is not supported for VM versions" but I'm using GAE only.

Also, during the first execution, the service asked me about some authorization, and I agreed with.

Is there some way to fix this? I could not find any explanation how to fix this issue.

Comment: I've only ever set that setting directly in the app.yaml and not in that UI, but try removing `standard_scheduler_settings`. I've never seen that before.  https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#scaling_elements

Comment: It seems that you have an application in the Flexible environment and are using the Mask for the Standard environment [automaticScaling.standard_scheduler_settings.min_instances]. You should use automaticScaling.min_total_instances instead.

Comment: @GonçaloAlbino is correct. I'm using GAE Flex environment for Python. So I was able to use `automaticScaling.min_total_instances`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@GonçaloAlbino observed that I used **Flex** environment instead of **Standard**. So I'm able to use `automaticScaling.min_total_instances`.

[image]